# How do I properly use an if then else statement with jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using a jQuery plugin called FullCalendar to make a calendar app. I made a tab to the left of the calendar that has tabs on it for each of the 6 weeks displayed on the calendar. So, for example, if you put your mouse over the "Week 1" tab it displays the agenda view of the first week of that month. I wanted to make it so that when your mouse went over the tab it displayed the week and when your mouse left the tab it went back to the normal month view. I got that part to work but I also want it so that when you actually click on the tab it stays on that view and doesn't switch back to the month view.

Here's the mouseover and mouseout part that works correctly:

```
<script>
$( '#week2' ).mouseover(function() {
    $('#week2').css('color', 'white');
    $('#week2').week2();
});
    $( '#week2' ).mouseout(function() {
        $('#week2').weekout();
        $('#week2').css('color', 'yellow');
    });
</script>
```

And just to re-iterate, all that does is when the user puts their mouse over the 'week2' tab it shows the week view of Week 2. This is the code that doesn't work that I'm using to try and make it when the user clicks in the tab it makes it stay on the view, even when the mouse leaves the tab:

```
<script>
var x = 0;
$( '#week1' ).click(function() {
    var x = 1;
});
$( '#week1' ).mouseover(function() {
    $('#week1').css('color', 'white');
    $('#week1').week1();
});
    $( '#week1' ).mouseout(function() {
        if(x < 1) {
            $('#week1').weekout();
            $('#week1').css('color', 'yellow');
        }
        else {
            null
        }
    });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that if the user clicks on the tab it sets x to 1 so then the mouseout() function doesn't run. But, it runs anyways :(

Comment: `var x` is redefined in a different scope entirely as you're using the var keyword twice !

Comment: You are defining again var x $( '#week1' ).click function, in the function must bel only x=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining again `var x` in the  `$( '#week1' ).click` function, so the variable lose its original global scope.

Change your code from:

```
$( '#week1' ).click(function() {
    var x = 1;
});
```

to:

```
$( '#week1' ).click(function() {
    x = 1;
});
```

Docs on var and scoping: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, the if says if(x < 1) so it depends